# Effect Analysis for any change in a .Net Core Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, code-analysis, visual-studio-2019

Is there any tool or way for analysing effects of any change on a method/class/assembly in a .Net Core solution ? For example, if I change an interface, which classes(or assemblies) will be affected from this change.

I use visual studio 2019 for development. I examined ndepend and resharper, but these two shows dependency graph but I want to see reverse of it which is caller(callee) graph.

Comment: ReSharper does this.. https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: @d.moncada I edited question.

Comment: NDepend can certainly help too, "if I change an interface"  so given an interface you want all methods that use it and all classes that implement it? "analysing effects of any change" what do you mean by effect? which code will be impacted if a method is added or removed for example?

Comment: thanks @PatrickfromNDependteam, yes what I mean by  "effects of any change" is any code part which uses changed code. I searched Ndepend more and I queried for callers, it solves some of my problem. Another part is views. Ndepend doesn't show razor views in callers' list.

Comment: Indeed by now *.Views.dll* assemblies are not resolved when referencing a .sln, but you can still create an NDepend project to references assemblies directly, including *.Views.dll* ones. Does NDepend full help in that case?

Comment: Just to let you know that *.Views.dll* assemblies are now taken account by NDepend v2021.1